# Powershell help, if process exists, stop it, else start a service?

Tags: powershell, scripting, shell, conditional-statements, powershell-cmdlet

I'm pretty new to Powershell. I have 2 different scripts I'm running that I would like to combine into one script.

Script 1 has 1 line

```
Stop-Process -ProcessName alcore.*  -force
```

It's purpose is to end any process that begines with "alcore."

Script 2 has 1 line as well

```
Start-Service -displayname crk*
```

It starts any service that begins with crk.

How can I combine these into one script? If the processes are running I wish to stop them, if not, I wish to start the services.  How can I accomplish this?

I'm trying this but it's not working

```
$services = Get-Process alcore.*

if($services.Count -qe 1){
    Stop-Process -ProcessName alcore.*  -force
} else {

    Start-Service -displayname crk*
}
```

How can I do this correctly? Also should I wrap these up in a function and call the function? That seems a bit cleaner.  Thanks for any help.

Cheers,
~ck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Get-Service to get the service status.  The process could be running but the service might be paused:

```
$services = @(Get-Service alcore.*)
foreach ($service in $services)
{
    if ($service.Status -eq 'Running')
    {
        $service | Stop-Service
    }
    else
    {
        Start-Service -DisplayName crk*
    }
}
```

Comment: you gave me some ideas. I ended up going this way.
$processes = @(gps tcore.*)

if($processes.Count -gt 0)
{
 kill -ProcessName tcore.* -force  
} else {
 sasv -DisplayName AMS*

}

Thanks, ~ck