# How to close a popup at the same time i close a service in powershell?

Tags: powershell, service, popup

I'm trying to make a pop up that will close at the same time than one of my software, i have tried several methods but I'm not able to do that, how could i verify if my service is still running ?, and how do i close my pop up when my service stop?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [timer](https://jrich523.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/creating-a-timer-event-in-powershell/) and check for the [service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143938/powershell-help-if-process-exists-stop-it-else-start-a-service) or [process](http://powershell.com/cs/forums/t/10908.aspx) every few seconds. If the process/ service is stopped/gone, close the popup.

Comment: even if i use a timer i need to restart it to reverify if my service is stopped, I've been trying for more of a week and I'm not able to find anything,

Comment: Why would you need to restart anything?
If you have a Popup, you have a Windows Form or WPF-Application running, right? If so just add the timer to your script and it will keep polling the service until you close your form (the popup).

Comment: Thank you, but what i need to do is close my pop up when my service will stop